# Can I switch around this function vanilla.count()

Tags: python, class, function

I am wondering if it is possible to write `count(vanilla)` instead of `vanilla.count()` ? It is similar to `len(list)` but I want to do `len(myclass)`. Is it possible to implement like this on my user define class? Below just a dummy class I wrote to ask this question. Thank you.

```
    class IceCream():
    # Flavor is a string
    # Toppings is a list of strings
    def __init__(self, flavor, toppings, ):
        self.name = flavor
        self.toppings = toppings
    # Return the number of toppings
    def count(self):
        return len(self.toppings)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} flavor ice cream".format(self.name)


vanillaToppings = ['chocolate chips', 'fudge', 'penuts']
vanilla = IceCream('Vanilla', vanillaToppings)
print(vanilla, 'with', vanilla.count(), 'kind of toppings!')
# Is it possible? If so, how do I do it?
# print(vanilla, 'with', len(vanilla), 'kind of toppings!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about utilizing one of python's [special methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html): [`__len__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)?

> Called to implement the built-in function len(). Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0.

```
class IceCream():
    # Flavor is a string
    # Toppings is a list of strings
    def __init__(self, flavor, toppings):
        self.name = flavor
        self.toppings = toppings

    # Return the number of toppings
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.toppings)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} flavor ice cream".format(self.name)


vanillaToppings = ['chocolate chips', 'fudge', 'penuts']
vanilla = IceCream('Vanilla', vanillaToppings)
print(vanilla, 'with', len(vanilla), 'kind of toppings!')
```

I would guess that the meaning of *count* and *length* are somewhat interchangeable in this case, so why not use something familiar?

Comment: Yes, I notice `__len__` works, but what if I want to do `__count__`? In that case is there anyway I can put it in my class instead of having it separate outside of my class?

Comment: No. `count()` is not a built-in function like `len()` is.

Comment: But we can overload all the built-in functions? (By overloading, I think I should say: we can define them as we see fit?)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Is the section under basic-customization and below... all the ones with two underscore, I can define them for my `IceCream` class?

Answer (score 2):

`len()` is a function that gets the length of whatever it is passed. So you can just write a function `count()` that is passed an object, and counts it (however you define "counting").

The `len()` function calls a special method, `__len__()`, on the instance. You could define a similar interface for `count()` so that those who want to use your function can define a special method on their own classes for use by `count()`. (Do not name it with two leading and two trailing underscores; this is reserved for Python. A single leading and trailing underscore would be my recommendation.) Then you just implement that interface on your own object.

So something like this:

```
def count(obj):
    return obj._count_()

class IceCream(object):
    def _count_(self):
        return len(self.toppings)
```

miku suggests just implementing `__len__()` on your class and using `len()`. That is a great solution too, but it might create the impression that other container or iterator methods are available.

Comment: Your suggestion is I write a `def count(IceCream):` method outside? Am I reading it correctly? Sorry I am a little confused on the second part in your answer. "Define a similar protocol"...?

Comment: @kindall: *but it might create the impression that other container or iterator methods are available* - interesting, I haven't thought of that right away; but iterating over the ice cream toppings might not be totally senseless either :)

Comment: The way you implement the `_count_` in the `IceCream` class, is it that the `count(vanilla)` will call the first one, while `vanilla.count()` calls the second one?

Comment: And on the side note, is it common for people to define `__len__` (or other build-in function) for their own class? Or usually they tend to write their own? I don't know what is it like in real world programming yet.

Comment: Yes, the basic idea is there are two parts: the function `count()` that calls the method, and the method `_count_()` that defines what actually is counted for each class. Have a look at how `len()` and `__len__()` work together and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html on which magic methods you can implement. What you want is `def __len__(self): return len(self.toppings)`

Then you can use `len(yourinstance)` to get the return value of that function.

You **cannot** do this for `count(yourinstance)` though; at least not in a clean way.

---

The non-clean way would be this:

```
def count(instance):
    return instance.count()
```

I'm not using `__count__` as `__*__` is considered reserved for official python things such as `__len__`. But anyway, please forget everything below the horizontal line a few lines above - you really don't want to do this. Use `__len__` for it.

Comment: Yea, I can see the non-clean way, (everytime the person has to use my class), they will have to "copy" a bunch of code, doesn't sounds like a good idea...

Comment: Actually `__*__` is merely used to denote some method/variable that should not be accessed directly. Python doesn't have protected methods/variables but the underscores are meant to denote something that should be 'protected'.

Comment: @JoelCornett: That's true for `__something`, but `__something__` does have a different meaning: *`__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.* ([PEP-008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) No name mangling occurs for those fields: http://codepad.org/almhNmMB